# While loop inside PyQt form not working

Tags: python-3.x, indentation, pyqt5

I'm using Python 3.4 and PyQt 5. I have written a while look Inside PyQt form. If the loop contains a single statement, it's working. But if the loop contains multiple statements, it's throwing an indentation error.

Below is working:

```
while count > 0: print("count value",count)
```

Below is throwing an indentation error:

```
while count>0: 
       print("count value", count)
       count = count -1
```

Please help me to solve the problem. The same code is working if I run it outside PyQt form code.

Comment: can you please send all track back error message

Comment: Not only stack trace but also more code would help (`count` initialization).

Comment: The error message: "Sorry: TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: I have edited and added the part of code